# Doing something wrong with simple integration

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

So far my problem is finding E(X). After all my attempts I have E(X) = a/(a+1), and even wolfram alpha backs me up on this, even though the answer my prof got was a/(a-1). Sorry it's a picture again, but my rough work

[image]

I believe my set up and integration was right, but somewhere in evaluating the limit I went wrong. It's such a simple mistake but it's so irritating.

Comment: Sorry, late night and near exams. Brain is scrambled looking at it 20 mins. I'll avoid in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is as you integrate

$$\int_1^\infty x^{-\alpha} \, dx = \left.\frac{x^{-\alpha+1}}{\color{red}-\alpha+1}\right|_1^\infty$$

Comment: Dang it. So everything else is correct?

Comment: It seems that with that correction, you should be able to get the same answer as your prof.